# Different time format on docker than locally

Tags: docker, date

I am running a webapp, normally i use it just locally with create react app, but as there was a bug I ran it with docker to see if i could spot more easily the issue, as it was not reproducible locally.

The issue is that locally, a datepicker has the format **day/month/year**, but when run in docker is **month/day/year**.

I am super new to docker,and I see the dockerfile has this:

```
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime
```

I tried changing it to

```
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime
```

But i still get the same format on the date pickers.

How can I change the date format on docker so that it is the same as locally: **day/month/year**

Comment: Do you know where this date picker actually gets its date format from? It might not be from the timezone, but from some other locale setting.

Comment: ENV TZ=Europe/Berlin ||
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone || https://docs.diladele.com/docker/timezones.html

Comment: @HCP thx tried but the date picker shows the same format :(

Comment: @KevinBoone No I do not know, im using pupeter to automate another site, the other site is out of my control.